# How to tokenize entire index automatically?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to automatically apply n-gram tokenization on an entire Elasticsearch index.

The docs mention ultimately running an analysis to apply a tokenizer, but the analyzer seems to require explicit string input to work on.

**Question:** How I can just tell ES to "analyze the entire index" (ie just scan and tokenize everything)?

**Context:** I have some ES indexes, mainly from a MYSQL database of simple postings (e.g. ads, events, user profiles), but some indexes are also fixed pre-determined lists of terms from JSON (e.g. 200 name brands, 400 tags, 20 categories, etc) that will rarely change. In any case, the content is simple; no massive articles and I don't index paragraphs. I'm trying to build clever autocomplete and suggestions from my apps' search bar and just want to do pre-analysis of existing and fixed content. Ultimately when there's more dynamic 'big data' from users, I'll integrate analysis of that.

**Relevant links:**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#update-settings-analysis

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html

**Attempt:**

Here I setup a tokenizer on an index:

```
// Close the particular index first
POST /my-index-000001/_close

// Apply new settings: tokenizer defined and included in an analyzer
PUT /my-index-000001/_settings
{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "my_analyzer": {
        "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
      }
    },
    "tokenizer": {
      "my_tokenizer": {
        "type": "edge_ngram",
        "min_gram": 2,
        "max_gram": 10,
        "token_chars": [
          "letter",
          "digit"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

// Re-open the index
POST /my-index-000001/_open
```

At this point nothing has happened yet. I have to run the analyzer on the index... but the analyzer requires explicit string input. Instead I want to just run it on everything currently stored in the index.

```
POST /my-index-000001/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",

  // Is there a way to just apply it to the entire index?
  "text": "The cat is black"
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Following Opster's answer, here's an adjusted script that works. For re-index'ing, as mentioned there's a few possibilities. I did have success with the index duplication method, however I forgot I had setup a re-index'ing script in my project too which is very convenient.

```
PUT /my-index-000001/_settings
{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "my_analyzer": {
        "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
      },
      "default": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
      }
    },
    "tokenizer": {
      "my_tokenizer": {
        "type": "ngram",
        "min_gram": 2,
        "max_gram": 10,
        "token_chars": [
          "letter",
          "digit"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I'll have a chance this weekend to follow up =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, you have an existing index where you want to apply the new `edge_ngram` tokenizer on all the fields, and what you just did is that defined you custom analyzer `my_tokenizer` which uses `edge_ngram` in your index settings and expect that all the fields will start using it, which is a wrong assumption as

1. Changing analyzer of a field is a breaking change and you have to again reindex all the documents to have tokens according to new analyzer.
2. You have not defined analyzer on fields also didn't define new analyzer as a default analyzer of your index, so it will never take impact on any field.

**Solution**

1. First you need to define your new analyzer as a default analyzer as shown in [this official example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/specify-analyzer.html#specify-index-time-default-analyzer).
2. Now for reflecting the changes, you have two options either update all the index again from your source of truth ie mysql in your case, or if you have `_source` field enabled in your old ES index, use [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) to create a new index from old ES index, which will be easier, faster and recommended way to reindex the data.

Comment: Hey you were spot-on with the advice. Edited the OP with updated script.